# Count Poisson Regression dataset

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-regression, poisson-distribution

I'm looking for a dataset which I can use in R modelled by the glm function with family=poisson. I need there to be at least four predictor variables and the count has to be the explanatory variable.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Your question is rather narrowly focused on R and `glm(..., family = poisson)`. This is typically regarded to be off-topic on this site. Also, the underlying question for recommendations about data sets is somewhat broader than recommended. See <https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic> for more details.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of packages which provide quite a few count regression examples. See for example package `countreg` on R-Forge (https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=522), or `AER` (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=AER) or `COUNT` (https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=COUNT) on CRAN. The `AER` package is more general but count data sets include `Affairs`, `CreditCard`, `DoctorVisits`, `EquationCitations`, `GSS7402`, `Medicaid1986`, `NMES1988`, `PhDPublications`, `RecreationDemand`, `ShipAccidents`.

For most of these datasets/models there are overdispersion and/or excess zeros present so that a more general model fits better, e.g., negative binomial, zero inflation or hurdle model.

If you need a well-fitting Poisson model, then `ShipAccidents` in `AER` would be worth a look. If it is ok to discuss the limitations of the Poisson model and show some generalizations, then I like the `CrabSatellites` data in the `countreg` package. See the examples on the corresponding manual pages for concrete models and illustrations.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a substantial list of datasets in the `R` package `datasets` [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html).  There may be some datasets there that meet your needs.  For example, the dataset [`UKDriverDeaths`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/UKDriverDeaths.html) has a count variable for driver deaths, with some other variables that could be used as covariates.

Comment: Hi Ben, when I load that data, the resulting dataset only includes the count. Could you assist me?

Comment: The `UKDriverDeaths` data is just the univariate time series. The `Seatbelt` data additionally offers various regressors. However, while the response is count data, the counts are so large that a Poisson model will fit rather poorly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, the British Doctor's Smoking and Lung Cancer dataset is ideal.

Regarding GLM with a Poisson family function, most Poisson regression packages can also handle GLM's log and linear link functions.  There are also geometric mixture models which can be handled by some packages.  The [Explorer](https://www.nxglogic.com/explorer.html) (free) package will identify what power-link function is best for a geometric mixture model between additive and multiplicative.  In summary, you commonly don't need GLM for many flavors of Poisson regression.